# How can I explain the function of filter and lambda in a line of code?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, filter, lambda

```
number_plates = ["DV61 GGB",      #UK
                 "D31 EG 2A",     #F
                 "5314 10A02",    #F
                 "24TEG 5063",    #F
                 "TR09 TRE",      #UK
                 "524 WAL 75",    #F
                 "TR44 VCZ",      #UK
                 "FR52 SWD",      #UK
                 "100 GBS 12",    #F
                 "HG55 BPO"       #UK
                 ]

# Find the non-UK plates
pattern = "(?![A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}$)"
foreign_numbers = list(filter(lambda x: re.match(pattern, x), number_plates))
```

This is a part of my code. The `foreign_numbers = list(filter(lambda x: re.match(pattern, x), number_plates))` has been done by someone else for me, and I know roughly that it puts number plates into a new list if it doesn't match the `pattern` of UK number plate structure. This is a task set by my teacher therefore I also need to explain different parts of code one by one.

My question is:
What do `filter` and `lambda` do in `foreign_numbers = list(filter(lambda x: re.match(pattern, x), number_plates))` that the foreign plates are placed in the new list because they don't match the pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to your question.

1. `lambda` is just a different way to write a function:

   ```
   def find_non_uk(x):
       return re.match(pattern, x)
   ```

   is the same as :

   ```
   find_non_uk = lambda x: re.match(pattern, x)
   ```

   `lambda` is rather limited in what you can do. It is essentially ilmited to one line and all has to be an expression. Using `def`, there are no such limitations. You can use multiple lines and statements in the function body.
2. `filter` applies the given function to each element of your list and returns only those elements of the list for which the return value is true. From the docstring:

   > filter(function or None, iterable) --> filter object
   >
   > Return an iterator yielding those items of iterable for which function(item)
   >   is true. If function is None, return the items that are true.

You could write your line like this:

```
foreign_numbers = list(filter(find_non_uk, number_plates))
```

You need the outer `list()` to turn the iterator into a list.

If this seems too complicated and you know list comprehensions, use them:

```
pattern = re.compile("(?![A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}$)")
foreign_numbers = [x for x in number_plates if pattern.match(x)]
```

Comment: By return, do you mean the filter returns the matching number plates to `number_plates` which they originally were in?

Comment: I mean a function return value. In this code `number_plates` is never changed. The return value of `filter` is, after it is converted into a list, stored in `foreign_numbers`.

Comment: Oh... I think I will need a flowchart explanation for that.

Answer (score 1):

In `list(filter(lambda x: re.match(pattern, x), number_plates))`, **filter** function itself returns a list of elements that passed the check (in this case matched regex pattern) -just like the filter we use to strain liquids to make sherbet. and **list**  function converts it into list. So

`foreign_numbers = list(filter(lambda x: re.match(pattern, x), number_plates))` is the code that separates matched numbers into a list called `foreign_numbers`

```
>>>print foreign_numbers
>>>['D31 EG 2A', '5314 10A02', '24TEG 5063', '524 WAL 75', '100 GBS 12']
```

The function of `lambda` is grab one by one element from `number_plates` list and passes to the `re.match`.

Comment: The question has the Python 3 flag. Your answer uses Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile the pattern into a [RegexObject](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject), you don't have to create a lambda, as you can just use the object's [**`match`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) method:

```
pattern = re.compile("(?![A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}$)")
foreign_numbers = list(filter(pattern.match, number_plates))
```

The `match` method gets called for every number plate, and if it matches, `filter` will keep it.